# Visual Studio Settings not Synchronized

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

According to [Synchronized Settings in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn135229.aspx),

> When you use the same personalization account to sign in to Visual Studio on multiple computers, by default your settings are synchronized on all computers.

I logged in to my Microsoft Account on my work computer in Visual Studio 2015 and checked `Tools | Options | Environment | Synchronized Settings` to ensure that the box is checked.

Then, on my laptop, I logged into my Microsoft Account in Visual Studio 2015 and settings are not coming down.  I have ensured that the checkbox under `Tools | Options | Environment | Synchronized Settings` is checked.

So, what else do I have to do to make sure my settings are pushed to the cloud and retrieved on another machine?